# Background Image Cycle - z index with smooth fade or transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

I realise there are some similar questions but please hear me out. I'm asking because the other answers haven't quite got me to a solution.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6z22kns/

I can get the images to cycle but I'm really struggling trying to make them fadeIn or just smoothly transition. Right now it just jumps from one image to the next as you can see in the fiddle. I've tried animate with a callback to fadeIn, amoungst other things but I just can't get it right. This has been killing me all morning.

```
var imageIndex = 0;
var imagesArray = ["https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg","https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.sm.jpg","https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg","https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.sm.jpg"];

function changeBackground(){
  var index = imageIndex++ % imagesArray.length;
  $(".bsh-images").eq(index).css({"z-index":"-997"});
  $(".bsh-images").eq(index-1).css({"z-index":"-998"});

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(changeBackground, 5000);
});
```

Comment: why not use fading: https://jsfiddle.net/k6z22kns/2

Comment: try the above fiddle, otherwise use plugin for carousal like as " jquery cycle2"

Comment: Thanks Pete, I think I over thought the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create an animation effect by using transitions/animations.In this example i have initially Set the opcaity of image to zero and then change the opacity of displaying image  to 1.and added transition for the image in css.
Or you can find so many plugins for the creating these types of image sliders

```js
var imageIndex = 0;
var imagesArray = ["https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg", "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.sm.jpg", "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg", "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.sm.jpg"];

function changeBackground() {
  var index = imageIndex++ % imagesArray.length;

  $(".bsh-images").eq(index).css({
    "z-index": "-997"
  }).addClass('show');
  $(".bsh-images").eq(index - 1).css({
    "z-index": "-998"
  }).removeClass('show');

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(changeBackground, 3000);
});
```

```css
.bsh-images {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -998;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

.bsh-images.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-bg-slides">
  <div class="bsh-images bsh-image-1 show" style="background: url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;"></div>
  <div class="bsh-images bsh-image-2" style="background: url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.sm.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat; "></div>
  <div class="bsh-images bsh-image-3" style="background: url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;"></div>
  <div class="bsh-images bsh-image-4" style="background: url(https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.sm.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;"></div>
</div>
```